# Ищу хорошую книгу по C# для Ubuntu

Tags: c#, linux, книги

Здравствуйте, я хочу углубленно изучить **язык программирования** **C#** и ищу для этого хорошую книгу, но проблема в том, что все книги, которые я нахожу, рассчитаны на пользователей **Windows**, на программу **Visual Studio** и т.п. Я понимаю, что работа с языком, функционал и написание кодов для **Windows** и **Linux** на 90% ничем не отличаются, но было довольно тяжко, когда работал с формами, например. В общем, без лишнего мусора, по делу:  
Есть ли книга по **C#**, написанная для пользователей **Linux**, чтобы не возникало проблем с библиотеками, интерфейсом, работой со средой и внешними данными? Или же я зря волнуюсь, мои опасения несущественны и я могу смело брать любую книгу по **C#**?

Comment: Книги, в которых описывается на язык, а работа с конкретной средой (Visual Studio, например) — плохи по определению. Ищите книгу, которая описывает сам язык.

Comment: Да, мне тоже так показалось, но даже если они написаны не конкретно для среды, то, как правило, уже предисловие надрывается от слов "Windows" и "Microsoft".

Comment: @Артем2013 язык, будь то C# или какой-то еще, одинаков на любой платформе. У него есть спецификация, и она должна соблюдаться в любой реализации данного языка. А потому если вам нужно изучить именно язык (а не мастерство клепания окошек например) то разницы никакой, ориентирована ли книга на пользователей Windows, или на пользователей любой другой ОС.

Comment: Хорошо, благодарю:)

Comment: А вообще, нашёл книгу "Герберт Шилдт - C# 4.0. Полное руководство", на первый взгляд, довольно хорошая, посмотрим, что будет дальше.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Если Вы выбрали для изучения C#, читайте не про Windows, а про платформу .NET. Что касается книг - если прочесть дальше названия первой главы, Вы увидите, что Microsoft упоминается в основном в контексте истории появления языка и среды .NET. Поставьте себе Mono - это одна из самых популярных реализаций .NET под Linux, и она есть в основных репозиториях популярных дистрибутивов Linux. И читайте Рихтера для понимания и братьев Албахари в качестве справочника по языку. Если знания начальные, предварите упомянутые мной книги Троелсеном или Шилдтом (выбирайте ту, что лучше пойдет).
И не читайте "любую книгу", ни по одному языку. Не начинайте абы с чего, не портите себе старт.

Comment: +1, но я бы не рекомендовал Шилдта.

Comment: Да, Mono сразу поставил, спасибо, почитаю эти, пока начал Шилдта.

Comment: VladD, почему?

Comment: @Артем2013: он известен многочисленными неточностями, заблуждениями и фактическими ошибками в своих книгах по C. Экстраполируя, можно предположить, что он и с C# не сильно разобрался.

Comment: Плохо, мне начало нравиться, как он пишет, теперь появилось предвзятое отношение... А что вы скажете насчет Троелсена?

Comment: >А что вы скажете насчет Троелсена?

Троелсен вполне неплохой дядька, пишет достаточно обстоятельно. В первых главах может быть некий упор именно на Visual Studio (очень маленький, на уровне "как cоздать проект в Visual Studio"), однако практически вся книга посвящена именно C# и .NET без упора на Windows-реализацию, а спектр затронутых тем достаточно широк, вплоть до не относящихся к C# напрямую WPF и ASP.NET .

Comment: Окей, попробую параллельно почитать обоих, думаю, хуже не будет)

Comment: Шилдт неплохо пишет в смысле стиля, но доверять ему в техническом смысле может быть рискованно.